# Alternatives to splice(2) with Unix Domain Sockets (UDS)

Tags: c++, splice, unix-socket, zero-copy

I'm trying to pass data from one UDS to another as quickly as possible in a C++ program, but UDS's don't support [splice](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/splice.2.html) (as fd_in). Are there any alternative that are supported by UDS's that are as close to zero-copy as possible?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084254/linux-splice-returning-einval-invalid-argument) was asked for UDP sockets but they never found any alternatives to splice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Strict Answering Mode

This is a long shot, but I think I remember when the `fuse` low-level interface gained `splice()` support.

So, you could implement a fuse driver to do what you want. However, this only makes sense if you **insist** on having a file-descriptor compatible interface. I suspect it's a non-trivial amount of work, although a project like `ntfs-3g`  might have it 
implemented.

---

#### Thinking Along:

Now, what are you trying to achieve?

In my experience, UNIX domain sockets are only for intra-machine inter-process communication, and chances are that the consumers of the data aren't actually interested in the file/stream nature of the interface.

If it's enough to just pass the data, you perhaps use `mmap` with `splice` here:

```
int fd;
char tmpfile[] = "/tmp/fooXXXXXX";
void *buffer;
int pfd[2];
ssize_t bytes;

fd = mkostemp(tmpfile, O_NOATIME);
unlink(tmpfile);
lseek(fd, 4095, SEEK_SET);
write(fd, "", 1);
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
buffer = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

pipe(pfd);
bytes = splice(s, NULL, pfd[1], NULL, 4096, SPLICE_F_MOVE);
splice(pfd[0], NULL, fd, NULL, bytes, SPLICE_F_MOVE);
```

**CAUTION**: Be aware, when splicing data from a mmap'ed buffer to a network socket, it is not possible to say when all data has been sent. Even if `splice()` returns, the network stack may not have sent all data yet. So reusing the buffer may overwrite unsent data.

Background information from [this HowTo](http://ogris.de/howtos/splice.html)

Comment: Thanks! Our interprocess communication is restricted to UNIX domain sockets for pseudo-technical reasons, but I'll see if I can work things from your example.